# Extract frames from a video results in abnormaly more frames for each fps by using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, fps, framerate

I have a job of using ffmpeg to extract the frames averagely from a video, with different fps. I use this command for it.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r specified_fps -q:v 2 image %4d.png`

And I have 3 questions about this task.

1. What I expect is that if I double the fps, the number of extracted frames will also get doubled. However, that's not the case. Take one of the input videos as an example. I get 2 extra frames for all the sample factors (80 / 158 / 236 / 392 v.s. 78 / 156 / 234 / 390). Does it related to the mechanism of picking/dropping frames when extracting frames from a video？ (credit to @Tom Yan)

**video info**

- Duration: 1min18s
- Frame rate mode: constant (CFR)
- Frame rate: 30.0 FPS
- Total number of frames: 2340

**Config setting & results**

| FPS | Actual num of frames | correct num of frames |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 78 |
| 2 | 158 | 156 |
| 3 | 236 | 234 |
| 5 | 392 | 390 |

2. I check for the output images, the extracted frames for different fps are totally different from each other. In other words, for example, the 1st image for fps=1 is not the same as the 1st image for fps=2. Is that legitimate? And is it possible for me the get some identical images for different fps?
3. The last problem is that for some videos I use, the difference between the 1st and 2nd image is different from the difference between the 2nd and 3rd. While for the remaining images, the differences become average. To be specific, there is only a slight change from 1st to 2nd frame, while for 2nd to 3rd, 3rd to 4th, and so on, the changes are the same, which is normally distributed according to the specified FPS. I am wondering why such a case happens? Does it relate to the I-frame, B-frame, P-frame, GOP, or IDR?

I am new to this field and cannot find some useful info from other places. I've tried my best to describe my questions clearly. Feel free to leave some comments. Any help would do me a great favor. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you instead use `-r 15` / `-r 10` / `-r 6` before `-i input.mp4` (with `-r 1` after `-i input.mp4` in all cases)? Also, how many frames / image files do you get if you use `1` for both `-r`?

Comment: @TomYan Thx for your answer, I think that if specify `-r specified_fps` before `-i input.mp4` will have the same effect as first convert the original video (fps=30) into a video in specified fps, then use `-r 1` after `-i input.mp4` to extract frames every second.

Comment: Also I've tried what you said, for `-r 15` / `-r 10` / `-r 6`, each get 158, 236 and 392 frames. For both `-r 1`, I get 2340 frames. Actually, (`-r 15`, `-r 1`) has the identical output as only,`-r 2` after. Because the 15/1 = 30/2 = 15. Same for (`-r 10`, `-r 1`) & `-r 3`  and (`-r 6`, `-r 1`) & `-r 5`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the real problem is, why you get 2 extra frames for all the sample factors (80 / 158 / 236 / 392 v.s. 78 / 156 / 234 / 390; the latter ones are divided from the total number of frames 2340). No idea *how* exactly ffmpeg pick/drop frames.

Comment: That's true, I'll try to figure it out. Thx for your help anyway.